# Object not changed in the parent classes Java

Tags: java, class, object, oop

Hello I have the following code that gives me a `NullPointerException` when I call
the function `child.any()`
Why this happens and how to solve this?

```
public main {
  public void main(String[] args) {
    Parent parent = new Parent();
    Child child = new Child();
    Tmp tmp = new Tmp();
    parent.setter(tmp);
    child.any();
  }
}

public Parent {
  Tmp tmp;
  protected void setter (Tmp tmp) {
    this.tmp = tmp;
  }
}

public Child extends Parent {
  protected void any() {
    tmp.printTmp();
  }
}

public Tmp {
  public void printTmp() { 
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }
}
```

Comment: @user16320675 so I will need to send objects to each child class as I did with the parent?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a setter in the child class also.
In your case `parent` and `child` are two different objects

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        Child child = new Child();
        Tmp tmp = new Tmp();
        parent.setter(tmp);
        child.setter(tmp);
        child.any();
    }
}

class Parent {
    Tmp tmp;

    protected void setter(Tmp tmp) {
        this.tmp = tmp;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    protected void any() {
        tmp.printTmp();
    }
    
    protected void setter(Tmp tmp) {
        this.tmp = tmp;
    }
}

class Tmp {
    public void printTmp() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Good read

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)